# How can I dynamically generate a/or some buttons in a grid?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Grid grid1 = new Grid();
    Button button1 = new Button();
    button1.Content = "Button";
    grid1.Children.Add(button1);
}
```

I want to add Buttons to the grid but somehow the window is empty and I don't know why.

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223259/how-to-create-element-dynamically-and-bind-it-in-wpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you don't see the buttons or the grid is because you have not assigned the Grid to the Content property of the MainWindow.

You should add the grid control inside the designer, so it gets defined as a member of the class. After that, you can add the buttons to the grid, as you were doing, without reinstantiating the grid.

Working example:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Button button1 = new Button();
        button1.Content = "Button";
        gridTest.Children.Add(button1);            
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid x:Name="gridTest"/>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank u very much <3

Comment: @Syst3m4nia From your reply I understand that the answer was useful to fix the problem. Could you upvote / mark the answer as accepted one?